# how to get key from build Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to get value key which contains in Widget build(), but it says 'Undefined'. Also, I need to get this value to another class. How can I do it?

I`ve tried to just take this value, but it says undefined error

```
String newValue = s; // It says Undefined
```

I also tried to get this value to another class but this method gives more errors :c

```
myCard c = myCard();
String classValue = c.s; // It says 'Only static members can be accessed in initializers' and 'The getter 's' isn`t defined for the class 'myCard' '
```

Here`s part of main.dart file

```
    class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      myCard createState() => myCard();
    }

    class myCard extends State<MyCard> {
      int myCount = count - 1;


      void click() {
        setState(() {
          print(titlecard);
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => setNewText())
          );
        });

      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Key s = Key(myCount.toString()); // I want to get this value
        return Center(
          key: s,
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text(titlecard[int.parse(s)]),
                  subtitle: Text(textcard),
                ),
                ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                  child: ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('Change Text'),
                        onPressed: click,
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(s);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }


    }

    class setNewText extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      SetNewText createState() => SetNewText();
    }

    class SetNewText extends State<setNewText> {
      myCard c = myCard();
      HomePageState s = HomePageState();
      String v = c.s; // To here
      final titleController = TextEditingController();
      final textController = TextEditingController();
      final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      List<String> titles = [''];
      void _submit() {
        setState(() {
          if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
            formkey.currentState.save();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            titlecard.removeAt(count-s.myCount);
            titlecard.insert(count-s.myCount, titleController.text);
            textcard = textController.text;

          }
        });

      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Change Title'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Form(
                      key: formkey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: titleController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Title'
                            ),
                            validator: (value) => value.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Title' : null,
                            onSaved: (value) => value = titleController.text,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: textController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Text'
                            ),
                            validator: (text) => text.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Text' : null,
                            onSaved: (text) => text = textController.text,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                  child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                  onPressed: _submit,
                ),
              ],
            )
        );
      }


    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use another dart file, say gv.dart, to store all the values that need to be used in other classes?  e.g. create a class gv and inside this class, create a static int intCount=0, you can then use gv.intCount in other classes.  Of course, you'll need to import gv.dart in other dart files.

Comment: Yes, you right, but Key must be in Widget which you want to identify. So it won't help me.

Comment: Are you trying to control widgetA inside widgetB of another class?  so that you want to get the key of widgetA inside widgetB?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just listening for values, one way of doing this is by listening to the value using Streams. You can initialize the class where the value can be Streamed and access it anywhere. Do note that once the Stream has been closed, you can only create a new Stream.

Here's a sample.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleStream extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleStream({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<SampleStream> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<SampleStream> {
  Counter counter = Counter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: counter.showCount,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
          int count = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data! : 0;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                  'You clicked the button $count times'),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.plus_one),
              onPressed: () {
                counter.setCount(++count);
              },
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    counter.disposeCount();
  }
}

class Counter {
  final _count = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Stream<int> get showCount => _count.stream;

  setCount(int count) {
    debugPrint('Stream sink: $count');
    _count.sink.add(count);
  }

  disposeCount() {
    _count.close();
  }
}
```

In this demo, `Counter` was initialized in `_MyHomePageState` and can only be accessed in the same class. Calling `counter.setCount(int)` updates the stream and the stream value can be listened to using StreamBuilder to fetch the snapshot.

[image: Demo]